# How can i hide an ul when it has no li inside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's supose i have this HTML:

```
<ul class="nested">
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
</ul>

<ul class="nested">
</ul>

<ul class="nested">
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to check which ul has no li, when page get loaded, and hide it.

It can be done using jquery as well.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the following jQuery.

```
 window.onload = function(){ // When the page has finished loading.
    $(".nested").each(function(){ // Check every "nested" class 
    if($(this).children().length == 0){ // If this nested class has no children
        $(this).hide(); // This will hide it, but not alter the layout
        // $(this).css("display", "none"); // This will alter the layout
        } else{
        $(this).show();
        //$(this).css("display", "none"); // This will alter the layout
        }
     }
}
```

Or, as user Rory McCrossan suggested, much more simply written :

```
window.onload = function(){
    $('.nested:not(:has(li))').hide(); // Will not alter layout
    // $('.nested:not(:has(li))').css("display", "none"); // Will alter layout
    }
```

Comment: Or just `$('.nested:not(:has(li))').hide()`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That is an incredible solution. Remarkably impressed as always. So much simpler. So much better.

Answer (score 7):

You only need CSS

> The :empty pseudo selector will select elements that contain either
>   nothing or only an HTML comment.

```
div:empty {
   display: none;
}
```

Source https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/e/empty/

Comment: Worth noting that the `<ul>` in question contains white-space, which the `:empty` selector won't match for.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, if the `ul` tag has anything even a white-space it will not match the :empty selector

Answer (score 0):

To do that by jQuery you can use `$.each` in jQuery...also theres a lot of possible option can resolve this issue

```js
$(".nested").each(function(index){
    if(!$(this).find("li").length){
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nested">
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
</ul>

<ul class="nested">
</ul>

<ul class="nested">
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
</ul>
```